# Global unique id for records

Tags: xml, database

I want to generate an unique id for my records kept in xml database,Whenever I generate an unique id ,I do not want to compare with already used Ids to check if it exists.I want to make a method which generates 100% unique id.I tried using timestamp but it fails if different time zones update the database. Is there any other way?

PS: I apologize in advance to people who can only read code on stack overflow,I dont have any code to post at the moment.

Comment: Can't you use UTC/GMT? It's standard and is not affected by timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (Universally Unique Identifier) for this which is guaranteed to be globally unique.